# MySQL, HiveQL, SQL: Combine sets

Tags: mysql, sql, hiveql

How do I combine sets? For example, I have the following table, `db.table1`:

```
cola    colb  colc
abc     1     [1, 2]
abc     1     [3]
```

I want:

```
abc  1    [1, 2, 3]
```

I tried:

```
SELECT cola, colb, COLLECT_SET(colc)
FROM db.tbl1;
```

which gives the error `FAILED: UDFArgumentTypeException Only primitive type arguments are accepted but array<string> was passed as parameter 1.` because it seems I cannot collect sets of sets.

Comment: What is datatype for `colc` field?

Comment: @Akina `array<string>`

Comment: MySQL (you have tagged your question with it) have no such datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

```
SELECT cola, colb, COLLECT_SET(b.col) AS colc
FROM db.table1
LATERAL VIEW EXPLODE(colc) b
GROUP BY cola, colb;
```

will return:

```
cola    colb  colc
abc     1     [1, 2, 3]
```